# Is /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf on Puppet4 equivilent to /etc/puppet/puppet.conf

Tags: puppet, puppet-agent

I often see tutorials and instructions referencing `puppet.conf` at `/etc/puppet/puppet.conf`.

I don't have this file but I do have `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf` on my computers with Puppet 4 installed. I just want to confirm that these two files are essentially equivilent?

Is it the case?

Comment: See also: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/whered_it_go.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are the globally the same. The location can differ depending on version or Operation system distribution. It could also differ between Puppet enterprise (premium paid) and the community version (free of charge). The documentation is having info about it.

https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/3.8/dirs_confdir.html (adapt to your version).